# Date Column for each Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to add a date column for each case statement I have.  The issue I am having is this date column is the same column for each element of the case statement, in the table. I am trying to figure out how to make the date unique to each case, without repeating the datetime column over and over.

```
CASE
            WHEN fe.name = 'Browse Markets'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS BrowseMarkets,
CASE
            WHEN fe.name = 'Market Viewed'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS MarketViewed,
CASE
            WHEN fe.name = 'Market added to watchlist'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS MarketAddedtoWatchList
```

The output of the data needs to look like:

BrowseMarkets| Timestamp | MarketViewed| TimeStamp | MarketAddedtoWatchlist | Timestamp

What I am trying to avoid doing is the following:

```
CASE
            WHEN fe.name = 'Browse Markets'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS BrowseMarkets,
fe.client_date,
CASE
            WHEN fe.name = 'Market Viewed'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS MarketViewed,
fe.client_date,

CASE
            WHEN fe.name = 'Market added to watchlist'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS MarketAddedtoWatchList,
fe.client_date
```

Is there a better way to achieve this desired result?

Comment: MySQL or Snowflake? Please tag only one database.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, and an entire query (not just a part of it).

Comment: Why would you want the same data 3 times on the table?  Just remove the extra timestamp columns.